# STDOUT and STDERR redirection for nc

Tags: bash, scripts, stdout, netcat

I am trying to make a watchdog bash script which has to check if the port is open, based on the exit status, otherwise should start the daemon. Problem is I can't manage to avoid the script outputting any information by redirecting STDOUT and STDERR.

```
nc -zv 1.2.3.4 55 | grep " open " >/dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
nc -zv 1.2.3.4 55 | grep " open " 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

or

```
nc -zv 1.2.3.4 55 | grep " open " &>/dev/null
```

returns anyway

```
'FQDN_hostname_or_domainname [1.2.3.4] 55 (?) open'
```

Nevertheless, this combo works with other commands, such as `netstat`. Is it something about netcat, or maybe about bash syntax? Please let me know what I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `nc` or `netcat` or any of their ilk. You are running two commands here, `nc` and `grep`, but only redirecting the output of `grep`. What you want to do is:

```
nc -zv 1.2.3.4 55  &>/dev/null
```

That, of course, would be pointless since if there's no output, you can't `grep`. That's what grep's `-q` flag is for:

```
   -q, --quiet, --silent
          Quiet;   do   not  write  anything  to  standard  output.   Exit
          immediately with zero status if any match is found, even  if  an
          error was detected.  Also see the -s or --no-messages option.
```

So, what you're after is something like this:

```
nc -zv 1.2.3.4 55 2>/dev/null | grep -q " open " && start_daemon
```

Or, if you need to parse stderr as well, this:

```
nc -zv 1.2.3.4 55  |& grep -q " open " && start_daemon
```

Comment: Seems that sdtout and stderr from netcat don't get piped into grep. While grepping "open", for example, netcat's output still gets displayed, even though was netcated a closed port, so there is no "open" in netcat's output message.

Comment: @RicardoBeschieru everything is piped, one way or the other. Worst case scenario, you might need to do something like `(nc -zv 1.2.3.4 55 2>/dev/null) | grep ...`, but that would be very surprising. What exact command are you running now?

Comment: I am running    `netcat -zvw1 1.2.3.4 55 | grep "open"`

Comment: @RicardoBeschieru does `nc -zv 1.2.3.4 55 2>&1 | grep open` work?

Comment: Yes, it does. It seems this is one of the differences between `nc` and `netcat` . My bad. Still is a mystery why output from `netcat` doesn't get piped to grep.

Comment: @RicardoBeschieru sorry, I was on mobile. I meant try `netcat -zvw1 1.2.3.4 55 2>&1 | grep "open"`. The thing is that some output is printed to stderr and some to stdout. If you just run `command | grep foo`, only stout is passed to `grep`. If you also want to grep stderr, you need `2>&1` or `&|`.

Comment: Yes, `netcat -zvw1 1.2.3.4 55 2>&1 | grep "open"` does work, so `nc -zvw1 1.2.3.4 55 2>&1 | grep "open"`. Turns out there is no difference betweeen nc and netcat in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get the script running properly using netcat's nc's exit status, while running it without -v option. Anyway, it seems that netcat's netcat's output doesn't get piped into grep. I suppose it might be caused by some sort of forking.

UPDATE:

As terdon mentioned in a comment to his answer, part of output from `nc` / `netcat` is printed to stderr, part to stout. So merging these two files before piping to grep does the trick:

`netcat -zvw1 1.2.3.4 55 2>&1 | grep "open"`